# Proof: if $b$ is inverse element of $a$ then $a$ is inverse element of $b$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I must prove the following:

**Property:** let $f$ a binary operation making $A$ a group, and $a,b \in A$ and $e$ is identity element, then if $b$ is inverse element of $a$ then $a$ is  inverse element  of $b$.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Do $a$ and $b$ have both sided inverses? $A$ is a group?

Comment: Is your operation associative?

Comment: @BabakS., sorry... yes, $A$ is group!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you want to show something like the following:

> Given any $a,b\in A$, if $f(a,b)=e$, then $f(b,a)=e$.

Since $A$ is a group, then the proof of this will rely fundamentally on the fact that $f$ is an associative operation--meaning that $f\bigl(f(a,b),c\bigr)=f\bigl(a,f(b,c)\bigr)$ for any $a,b,c\in A$--and that $f(x,e)=x$ for all $x\in A$ since $e$ is the identity.

Suppose $f(a,b)=e$, and let $c\in A$ such that $f\bigl(f(b,a),c\bigr)=e$--that is, let $c$ be the inverse of $f(b,a)$. Now, note that $$\begin{align}f\bigl(f(b,a),f(b,a)\bigr) &= f\Bigl(f\bigl(f(b,a),b\bigr),a\Bigr) &\text{[assoc.]}\\ &= f\Bigl(f\bigl(b,f(a,b)\bigr),a\Bigr) &\text{[assoc.]}\\ &= f\bigl(f(b,e),a\bigr) &\text{[}f(a,b)=e\text{]}\\ &= f(b,a) & \text{[ident.]}\end{align}$$ so by definition of $c$ and the work above we have $$\begin{align}e &= f\bigl(f(b,a),c\bigr)\\ &= f\Bigl(f\bigl(f(b,a),f(b,a)\bigr),c\Bigr)\\ &= f\Bigl(f(b,a),f\bigl(f(b,a),c\bigr)\Bigr) & \text{[assoc.]}\\ &= f\bigl(f(b,a),e\bigr)\\ &= f(b,a), & \text{[ident.]}\end{align}$$ as desired.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\rm\ ab = 1 = ba\ $ is *symmetric* in $\rm\:a,b.$